# Python: How to automate 'Allow' flash player content in Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, flash, firefox-profile

I need to allow flash content in an automated manner in Python. I tried using Selenium in Python to do so but could not manage. The issue is that browsers stopped supporting settings that always allow flash content. Moreover, the "Allow" button cannot be accessed via Selenium for instance because it is not a part of the website or a setting in Firefox. Does anyone know about a potential workaround?

Here is an image of the Firefox message that I need to somehow access:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYuRV.png]

Comment: Have you checked if there is an option to always allow it?

Comment: They removed this option in 2017 regrettably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"...The `Allow` button cannot be accessed via Selenium for instance because it is not a part of the website or a setting in Firefox. Does anyone know about a potential workaround?"*

I don't know your OS but if it was my problem...

- Try to find a "key press" module to send the `A` key press into Firefox (ie: the `Allow` shortcut).
- Try to send a mouse-click at the coordinates of `Allow` button.

A good option to try is [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html). Once Flash is enabled by such module (clicker or presser) then you can involve Selenium for whatever you needed to do in the enabled Flash.

Answer (score 2):

To allow **flash** content in an automated manner using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) through Python you need to use an instance of `FirefoxProfile()` and `set_preference()` method to configure:

- **`dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so`** to **`true`**
- **`plugin.state.flash`** to **`2`**

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so","true")
profile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This solution is no longer valid for Firefox and other browsers as these preferences can no longer be set for flash content.